# conditional with logical operators not executing as intended

Tags: javascript, object, web, conditional-statements, logical-operators

an if condition is not executing as expected in my code below. Function isPlaying when called by the eventListener down below is showing the status of the function as 'playing' even when the this.guesses variable = 0, and changes at to finished or failed at guesses = -1 which causes an extra keypress to display the finished or failed message. If I change the condition to this.guesses>1 status changes right away. I am confused.

```
    const Hangman = function(word,guesses){
    this.word = word.toLowerCase().split(''),
    this.guesses = guesses,
    this.guessedLetters = []
    this.status = 'playing';
}

Hangman.prototype.isPlaying = function(){
    const isWordMissing = this.wordPuzzle().includes('*');
    if(this.guesses > 0 && isWordMissing){
        this.status = 'playing';
    }else if(this.guesses > 0.5 && !isWordMissing){
        this.status = 'finished';
    }
    else if(this.guesses === 0){
        this.status = 'failed';
    }
}
Hangman.prototype.wordPuzzle = function(){
    let puzzle = ''
        this.word.forEach((letter) => {
            if(this.guessedLetters.includes(letter) || letter === ' '){
                puzzle += letter;
            }else{
                puzzle += '*';
            }
        })
        return puzzle;
}
Hangman.prototype.guessLetters = function(letter){
    guess = letter.toLowerCase();
    const isUnique = !this.guessedLetters.includes(letter.toLowerCase());
    const isBadGuess = !this.word.includes(letter.toLowerCase());

    if(!this.guessedLetters.includes(letter.toLowerCase())){
        this.guessedLetters.push(letter);
    }
    if(isUnique && isBadGuess){
        this.guesses = this.guesses - 1;
    }
}

game = new Hangman('fast',3);
const puzzleEl = document.querySelector('#word');
const guessEl = document.querySelector('#guess-left')
puzzleEl.textContent = game.wordPuzzle();   
guessEl.textContent = `Guesses remaining: ${game.guesses}`;
console.log(game.status);

window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if(game.status !== 'playing'){
        console.log(game.status)
    }
    else{
    const guess = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    game.guessLetters(guess);  
    puzzleEl.textContent = game.wordPuzzle();   
    guessEl.textContent = `Guesses remaining: ${game.guesses}` 
    debugger;
    game.isPlaying()
    }      
})
```

Comment: How are you checking the `status` after `game.isPlaying()`?

Comment: the first condition up on the top game.status !== 'playing', i moved the condition around to check if the problem was coming from the eventlistener itself but i didnt make any difference

Comment: Well, that check will only be executed at the beginning of a keypress. It won’t be rechecked after `game.isPlaying()`.

Comment: check is  meant to happen before a call to the guessLetters method ( that is where the number of guesses are decremented, which used in the conditionals of isPlaying method ) rather than the next keystroke??

Comment: I mean, wouldn’t it work as expected if you rewrote your event listener to `if (game.status === 'playing') {` _… the block from `const guess` to `game.isPlaying()` …_ `} console.log(game.status);`? Also, shouldn’t `this.guessedLetters.push(letter);` be `this.guessedLetters.push(letter.toLowerCase());`?

Comment: I tried that, it still needs 4 keystrokes instead of three to display failed message in the console

Comment: I guess the conditional statement to update this.status in isplaying() method is playing up for some reason. I am utterly confused at this point. Good call on the lowecaps method, thanks. I also used debugger to track down the values of the variables in isPlaying, they are all throwing out the correct values and the conditional statement is not executing despite that

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/6u4w8gLh/2/. After three wrong button presses, `failed` appears in the console.

Comment: You are right it works there for me too. It doesnt when i try natively on firefox or on chrome for that matter

Comment: Also, at `guess = letter.toLowerCase();`, why are you not declaring `guess`? Shouldn’t that just be `letter` instead of `guess`? Then you wouldn’t need to add `.toLowerCase();` everywhere. And replace the two commas around `this.guesses = guesses` by semicolons. Also, declare `game`. See if any of this fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the mistakes, fixed them all but no luck

Comment: I pasted the code from the fiddlejs back to the file on my computer and now its working despite all of the errors you mentioned above

Comment: Ok so i tried to play around with the code and turns out it was the logic, you were right about my logic.